# How to show response.body form from retrofit in a spinner

Tags: android, retrofit, spinner

I am trying to show some database info that i get with retrofit, but the problem is it won't appear the first option to select, it's just blank.
First of all I am creating the retrofit object to connect with my database.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://invazoras-g5-back-desa.herokuapp.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    final HerokuService service = retrofit.create(HerokuService.class);
    cargarPlantasInvasoras(service);
```

Here I am calling the function where i connect to the database and retrieve a list of objects, that in this case it's a list of Plants.

```
private void cargarPlantasInvasoras(HerokuService service) {
    plantasInvasorasNombre = new ArrayList<>();
    plantasInvasorasID = new ArrayList<>();
    Call<List<Plant>> call = service.plant();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Plant>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Plant>> call, Response<List<Plant>> response) {
            for (Plant p : response.body()) {
                plantasInvasorasNombre.add(p.getName());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Plant>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And here I created a Serial class that helps me to serializad the response body

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Planta {
@SerializedName("id_plant")
String id_plant;

@SerializedName("name")
String name;

public String getId_plant() {
    return id_planta;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the response is fully done you should be able to set the adapter with the new items.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Plant>> call, Response<List<Plant>> response) {
       for (Plant p : response.body()) {
            plantasInvasorasNombre.add(p.getName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,plantasInvasorasNombre);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);             
}
```